# Google static maps custom icons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

Does the premium plan allow for more than five custom icons on a map ?  I need about 20 different icons - the icons are circle with a number from 1 to 20 inside. It works fine up to 5 which is the rule but is possible to have more than 5

Answer (score 1):

Premium plan users have the same limit of 5 different custom icons in Static Maps API.

Somebody requested more than 5 different icons in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35825584

However, the Google staff answered the following:

> Increasing the number of custom icons would increase the overall latency of the API requests, as the icons each take their own time to be fetched. Issue 207 (KML support) or other layer-rendering solutions would be a more robust solution: you can have KML + many icons in a KMZ file, which only needs 1 outbound request to fetch it.

Hopefully, one day Static Maps will support KML layers. At the moment it is the following feature request:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35817020

Feel free to star it.